# Seaborn barplot ordering by bar length

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I am trying to plot barplot using seaborn.

```
k= 'all'
k_best = SelectKBest(k=k)
k_best=k_best.fit(features, labels)
features_k=k_best.transform(features)
scores = k_best.scores_ # extract scores attribute
pairs = zip(features_list[1:], scores) # zip with features_list
pairs= sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True) # sort tuples in descending order
print pairs

#Bar plot of features and its scores
sns.set(style="white")
ax = sns.barplot(x=features_list[1:], y=scores)
plt.ylabel('SelectKBest Feature Scores')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

My plot looks like this
[image]

I want the bars to be sorted in descending order.Exercised_stock_options with highest value on left followed by total_stock_value and so on.

Kindly help.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two lines

```
pairs = zip(features_list[1:], scores) # zip with features_list
pairs= sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)
```

already give you a list of tuples, sorted by the `scores` values. Now you only need to unzip it to two lists, which can be plotted.

```
newx, newy = zip(*pairs)
sns.barplot(x=newx, y=newy)
```

A full working example:

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ["z","g","o"]
y = [5,7,4]

pairs = zip(x, y)
pairs= sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse= True)

newx, newy = zip(*pairs)
ax = sns.barplot(x=newx, y=newy)

plt.show()
```

[image]